# React Native: <script> tag not working in react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

I've created a simple html page and loading it into WebView :

```
const OurStoryHTML = require ('./test.html');
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

<WebView
  source={OurStoryHTML}
  originWhitelist={["*"]} 
/>
```

My webpage contains the following tag:

```
<script async="async" src='http://www.youvisit.com/tour/Embed/js2'></script>
```

However, the script seems not to be loading in react-native-webview but works fine in the browser. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Try add `javaScriptEnabled={true} //enabling JavaScript` in `WebView's` props?

Comment: @高鵬翔  by default  javaScriptEnabled is true

Comment: Or maybe use `https` instead?

Comment: And is there async just use without `" "` ? [async](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp)

Comment: If you have expo it'll not work

Answer (score -2):

You must put double curly braces after source prop in WebView

source={{OurStoryHTML}}